# Autocompletion on TeXShop does not work properly

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

I have just discovered that TeXShop should have this function, as described in section [1.16 Auto Completion](http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/TeXShopManual-2006.pdf) of this manual. Now, by default I should have the autocompletion for `"`, which should be replaced by ``` ``#SEL##INS#'' ```, for `^` with `^{#SEL##INS#}` and so on.

The rules for those substitutions are contained in the file `autocompletion.plist` in such a way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">

<!--  
    Advanced users can change the default auto completions with this file. 

    The file format is very simple. Each entry is a pair. The first entry is the character
    to be modified. The second entry is the string which will replace it. If this string
    contains #SEL#, then this string should replace the current selection; otherwise it
    will be added to the current selection. If the string contains #INS#, then the cursor
    will be placed at this location.

    For example, the character ^ is replaced by ^{ } and the cursor is placed between
    these brackets using the pair

        <key>^</key>
        <string>^{#SEL##INS#}</string>

--> 


<dict>
    <key>"</key>
    <string>``#SEL##INS#''</string>
    <key>^</key>
    <string>^{#SEL##INS#}</string>
    <key>_</key>
    <string>_{#SEL##INS#}</string>
%... and so on %
```

The problem is that if i type `"`, `^`, `_` on the TeXShop editor I don't get the proper substitution, in fact I don't get an autocompletion at all. Does anyone knows why? And how do I fix this?

Comment: Do you have "Key Bindings" clicked in the Editor part of the Source panel of the TeXShop preferences?

Comment: Ok, that solved the problem, I didn't know I would have had to activate it, thanks!

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to activate the command completion you need to make sure that the Key Bindings option is selected in the TeXShop preferences:

[image: preference panel]