# autocomplete does not work texshop

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

I'm trying texshop as new tex editor from texmaker and I'm struggling with autocomplete. Looking around like here [Autocomplete with recent words in Texshop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280189/autocomplete-with-recent-words-in-texshop) and here  [Autocompletion on TeXShop does not work properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400931/autocompletion-on-texshop-does-not-work-properly) seems that is a config issue.
However after selecting key bindings in my preference-> editor settings it is still not working at all (i.e no suggestion). Is there something obvious that I am missing?
I would ned to have both tex and bibtex autocompletion.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Currently your question is difficult to answer, because it is not really clear what you mean with 'it does not work at all'. Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82382/does-texshop-for-mac-have-key-bindings can help you further?

Comment: What are you expecting? Do you mean Command Completion or Key Bindings? I’m not sure why you want to use TeXShop as an editor for TeXmaker since both are complete front ends for a TeX Distribution.